# Vaadin Loading Spinner

Tags: vaadin, spinner

Looking for a way to add a Loading Spinner as gif into my Vaadin 14 App. I only find a solution where i can create a "curtain" which is a layover over the screen. But dont get it done to add a gif which is spinning while loading. Does anyone have this already got to work?

Answer (score 1):

Its so easy to change the color:

just add

```
.v-loading-indicator {
background-color: blue !important;
}
```

to the main.css

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Vaadin Flow app, you can add an `Image` for the gif, and then remove it once the loading is complete.

Since it sounds like you are doing long-running tasks on the backend, you will probably want to use `@Push` in the application so you can notify the browser when the work is complete.

```java
UI ui = UI.getCurrent(); // get the instance before running a new thread
backendService.longRunningTask()
            .addCallback(
                new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                        ui.access(
                            () -> {
                                // setup for error
                                spinner.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        );
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                        ui.access(
                            () -> {
                                // setup for task completed
                                spinner.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
```

See this Vaadin Cookbook example for a complete example https://cookbook.vaadin.com/long-running-task

Comment: Its not a long running task, the problem is, that the loading bar is the same color as my header. (its a loading bar i think in the demo app of vaadin) But i would prefer a gif, centered on the Screen